# My Do Until macro doesn't do anything

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm creating an iterative loop for solving a Darcy-Weisbach closed pipe loop.  There are 4 loops.  I'm trying to repeat an iteration for all 4 loops until the head loss is below a certain value (0.0001).  I recorded a macro and then tried to modify it for as many iterations as it would take to get below that 0.0001.  The macro is basically pulling values from previous iterations and loops and placing them into a new iteration.  I'm really new to vba and I'm not really sure what the problem is here, but the macro won't run at all.  It doesn't say there are any errors, it just doesn't do anything.  Maybe someone knows what the problem is?

```
Sub Iterate()
'
' Iterate Macro
'
'
Dim RowStart As Long
Dim HeadLoss As Long
Dim Count As Long
    RowStart = 19
    HeadLoss = 0
    Count = 2
Do Until HeadLoss <= 0.0001
' Copy Previous Iteration
    Range(Cells(RowStart, 1), Cells(RowStart + 32, 7)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 34, 1)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 34, 1)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Iteration" & Count
' Loop 1
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 37, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 38, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-18]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 39, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 40, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-29]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 37, 7)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R61C5"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 37, 7)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 37, 7), 
        Cells(RowStart + 40, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Loop 2
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 45, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-5]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 46, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 47, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 48, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-18]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 45, 7)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R69C5"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 45, 7)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 45, 7), 
        Cells(RowStart + 48, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Loop 3
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 53, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 54, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-50]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 55, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-16]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 56, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-29]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 53, 7)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R77C5"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 53, 7)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 53, 7), 
        Cells(RowStart + 56, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Loop 4
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 61, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-5]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 62, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 63, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 64, 2)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-16]C[5]"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 61, 7)).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R84C5"
    Range(Cells(RowStart + 61, 7)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 61, 7), 
        Cells(RowStart + 64, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault

    HeadLoss = Cells(RowStart + 41, 5).Value + Cells(RowStart + 49, 5).Value +   
        Cells(RowStart + 57, 5).Value + Cells(RowStart + 65, 5).Value
    RowStart = RowStart + 34
    Count = Count + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

---

Thanks for the help guys, I'm definitely getting close.  I still have one more issue though.  I want the macro to loop until HeadLoss is less than 0.0001.  Currently the iteration will only run once and the HeadLoss is about 0.2058, which is obviously greater than 0.0001.  Why is it stopping after only one iteration?

```
Sub Iterate()
'
' Iterate Macro
'

'
Dim RowStart As Long
Dim HeadLoss As Long
Dim Count As Long
    RowStart = 19
    HeadLoss = 1
    Count = 2
Do While HeadLoss >= 0.0001
' Copy Previous Iteration
    With ActiveSheet
    Range(.Cells(RowStart, 1), .Cells((RowStart + 32), 7)).Copy 
          .Cells(RowStart + 34, 1)
    .Cells(RowStart + 34, 1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Iteration" & Count
' Loop 1
    .Cells(RowStart + 37, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 38, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-18]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 39, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 40, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-29]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 37, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R61C5"
    .Cells(RowStart + 37, 7).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 37, 7),
        Cells(RowStart + 40, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Loop 2
    .Cells(RowStart + 45, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-5]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 46, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 47, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 48, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-18]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 45, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R69C5"
    .Cells(RowStart + 45, 7).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 45, 7), 
        Cells(RowStart + 48, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Loop 3
    .Cells(RowStart + 53, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 54, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-50]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 55, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-16]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 56, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-29]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 53, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R77C5"
    .Cells(RowStart + 53, 7).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 53, 7), 
        Cells(RowStart + 56, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Loop 4
    .Cells(RowStart + 61, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-5]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 62, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 63, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 64, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-16]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 61, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R84C5"
    .Cells(RowStart + 61, 7).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 61, 7),     
        Cells(RowStart + 64, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Check to see if another iteration is needed
    HeadLoss = Abs(Cells(RowStart + 41, 5).Value) + 
        Abs(Cells(RowStart + 49, 5).Value) + 
        Abs(Cells(RowStart + 57, 5).Value)+       
        Abs(Cells(RowStart + 65, 5).Value)
    RowStart = RowStart + 34
    Count = Count + 1
    End With
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: `Do Until HeadLoss <= 0.0001` doesn't meet condition to enter your loop. Change into `Do While...`

Comment: `Do While HeadLoss > 0.0001`. Also, Have you tried adding breakpoints to the macro to see where it stops? and to check what all your values are?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Iterate()
    '
' Iterate Macro
'
'
Dim RowStart As Long
Dim HeadLoss As Long
Dim Count As Long
    RowStart = 19
    HeadLoss = 0
    Count = 2
Do While HeadLoss <= 0.0001
' Copy Previous Iteration

   With ActiveSheet
    Range(.Cells(RowStart, 1), .Cells((RowStart + 32), 7)).Copy .Cells(RowStart + 34, 1)

    .Cells(RowStart + 34, 1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Iteration" & Count

For i = 1 To 4
    .Cells(RowStart + 37, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 38, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-18]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 39, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-34]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 40, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-R[-29]C[5]"
    .Cells(RowStart + 37, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-R61C5"
    .Cells(RowStart + 37, 7).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(RowStart + 37, 7), Cells(RowStart + 40, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault
Next i

    HeadLoss = .Cells(RowStart + 41, 5).Value + .Cells(RowStart + 49, 5).Value + .Cells(RowStart + 57, 5).Value + .Cells(RowStart + 65, 5).Value
    RowStart = RowStart + 34
    Count = Count + 1
   End With
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Ya thanks, I fixed that part.  But now I'm getting a message saying "Runtime error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. It highlights the first line, "Range(Cells(RowStart + 34, 1)).Select"

Comment: Ok, should be all set now. I have tested it.